# Spring boot Restful API + Oauth2 + Angular - Logout if user not activity for a period of time

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I follow this articles: https://dzone.com/articles/secure-spring-rest-with-spring-security-and-oauth2 to build my website with angular.
As you can see, when i get a access token, it will have response like:

> `{
>       "access_token": "e494487f-0852-4857-bfa9-ead26ea382f7",
>       "token_type": "bearer",
>       "refresh_token": "7821c274-8c6e-492a-ad9a-0215ef3f037f",
>       "expires_in": 29,
>       "scope": "read write"
>   }`

Normally, when `access_token` expried I use `refresh_token` for get new `access_token`. And in angular, i just redirect to /login page or request new access_token from refresh_token.

Now, my user dont want this. That's mean, my user want to logout if user not activity for `xxx` (eg. 5 min) time, not follow my `access_token` `expires_in`. So how can I do that with spring oauth2 (back-end)?
Anyone can help me solution to resolve this, please?

Comment: dont give way to refresh token it will automatically redirect to login

Comment: @silentsudo the issue is my user dont want to redirect to login after access token expired, because my user in active on website.

Comment: It like session timeout, when you not activity for a period time. You will automatically logout.